# Dimension, Orbits, G-morphisms, Function Spaces, Finite Groups

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, vector-space-isomorphism

I am reading Group Theory and Physics by Sternberg.  On page 64, Section 2.5 Actions on function spaces, he states that:

$$ \text{dim} \space \text{Hom}_{G}(F(M),F(N))$$ **is the number of orbits of $G$ in $N \times M$.** I am asking why.

**Notation**:  $G$ is a finite group.  $M$ and $N$ are finite sets.  $F(M)$ and $F(N)$ are the vector space of all complex-valued functions on $M$ and $N$, respectively.

The context is that we are given an action of $G$ on $F(M)$ and $F(N)$:

$$a f(x) = f(a^{-1} x) \quad \forall a \in G$$
$$a h(y) = h(a^{-1} y) \quad \forall a \in G$$

where $x \in M$, $f \in F(M)$, $y \in N$ and $h \in F(N)$.

$\text{Hom}(F(M),F(N))$ is the vector space of all linear maps from $F(M)$ to $F(N)$.

$$T_{K} \in \text{Hom}(F(M),F(N)) \implies (T_{K}f)(y) = \sum_{x \in M} K(y,x)f(x) \quad \forall (y,x) \in N \times M$$

where $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, and $K: N \times M \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a function we can associate with $T$; it describes what $T$ does to $f$.  As the notation suggests, there is a bijective map $Z: F(N \times M) \rightarrow \text{Hom}(F(M),F(N))$, such that $Z(K) = T_K$.  This map is a vector space isomorphism from $F(N \times M)$ to $\text{Hom}(F(M),F(N))$.

Finally, adding a subscript $G$ to $\text{Hom}$ indicates the subspace containing $T_K$ which are fixed by the action of the group.

$$\text{Hom}_{G}(F(M),F(N)) = \{T_K \in \text{Hom}(F(M),F(N)) \quad \vert \quad r^{\text{Hom}}(a)T_K = T_K \quad \forall a \in G \}$$

where $r^{\text{Hom}}$ is a representation of $G$ on $\text{Hom}(F(M),F(N))$.

**Background and confusion**:  After proving that the isomorphism $Z$ is a $G$-morphism, Sternberg demonstrates that:

$$T_{K} \in \text{Hom}_{G}(F(M),F(N)) \implies K(a^{-1}y, a^{-1}x) = K(y,x) \quad \forall a \in G$$

meaning $K$ must be constant on the orbits of $G$ on $N \times M$.  I think I understand (at least, follow) this.

What is not clear is how this determines the dimension of $\text{Hom}_{G}(F(M),F(N))$.  There is obviously some one-to-one correspondence with $K$ being constant on the orbits of $N \times M$ and some analogous statement about the $T_K$, but I'm not making the connection.

Comment: You have defined $F(M)$ and $F(N)$ as the spaces of all complex-valued functions on $M$ and $N$, respectively. What is $F(M\times N)\,$? Is this a space of of all complex-valued functions on $M\times N\,$?

Comment: Yes, it is the vector space of all complex valued functions on $M \times N$.  I have edited the question to say vector space, rather than just space.

Comment: May I ask you a stupid question: why exactly is $Z(K) = T_K$ an isomorphism? To prove this, Sternberg demonstrates, on page 63, that (a) dim $F(M\times N)$ = dim Hom $(F(M),\,F(N)\,)$ and (b)  Ker $Z = 0$. Being necessary, are these two conditions sufficient? Would it not be necessary to bring in the continuity of $T$? Or that Z is a homeomorphism?

Comment: We are talking about an isomorphism between vector spaces, so all we require is a bijective linear map.  $Z(K) = T_K$ is linear because $Z(\lambda K) = T_{\lambda K}$ which acts on $f$ by $(T_{\lambda K} f)(y) = \sum_{x \in M} \lambda K(y,x)f(x) = (\lambda T_{K} f)(y) \implies T_{\lambda K} = \lambda T_{K} = \lambda Z(K)$ because $f$ was an arbitrary function in $F(M)$.  A similar argument will show that $Z(K + K') = T_{K+K'} = T_{K} + T_{K'} =   Z(K) + Z(K')$.  End of linear proof.  $Z$ is bijective because it has trivial kernel.  So, given $Z$ is linear, those two conditions are sufficient.

Comment: Understood. Thank you. So the third condition is just linearity -- and it is obeyed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This implication is actually a biconditional. The point is that $\operatorname{Hom}_G(F(M),F(N))$ is isomorphic to the subspace of $F(N \times M)$ consisting of those functions $K$ which are constant on orbits. The dimension of this subspace is the number of orbits, because it has a basis consisting of functions which take the value $1$ on a particular orbit and $0$ everywhere else.